# Динамическое создание DOM элементов или отображение уже существующих?

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть 9 меню, которые нужно отрисовывать по нажатию на соответствующие кнопки. Как лучше это реализовать: через динамическое создание по средствам js, или сразу отрисовать в html, кинуть их в "display: none" и, по необходимости, менять параметр display? И будет ли нагружать сайт элементы в "dispay: none"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если эти элементы и их контент статичны - то я бы предложил создать (а лучше сделать один компонент и переиспользовать его) и условно показывать. Контент же можно генерировать для них также через одну функцию, если это одинаковые меню с разным контентом. Полная же генерация через JS будет дольше и она не будет ни чем оправдана, так что такой способ подойдёт для весьма специфичных кейсов. Элементы с `display: none` все ещё остаются в DOM, но не рендерятся, поэтому влияние на производительность в нашем случае будет ничтожно.